Rust Generic with trait constraint, where trait also has a generic with a trait constraint
The following example is the simplest I can come up with to try to illustrate what I'm struggling to achieve:
pub trait Recipient {
    fn receive(&self, number: i32);
}

pub trait RecipientCatalog<R: Recipient> {
    fn lookup<'a>(&self, recipient_index: usize) -> &'a R;
}

pub struct NumberDispatch<C>
where C: RecipientCatalog<R> { 
    catalog: C
}

impl<C> NumberDispatch<C>
where C: RecipientCatalog<R> { 
    pub fn dispatch(&self, number: i32) {
        let recipient_index = 0; // Would be lookup logic
        self.catalog.lookup(recipient_index).receive(number);
    } 
}

In the example, the NumberDispatch should be able to dispatch a given number to some resolved Recipient implementation (lookup logic is not important for the example). However, this code does not compile as it is as type "R" is not defined. But I can not figure out how to define what R is in the NumberDispatch struct.
The idea is that the API user will provide a RecipientCatalog of some type, that provides references to something that implement the Recipient trait. Then the NumberDispatch should be able to pass a number to some resolved Recipient, by looking it up in the provided RecipientCatalog implementation.
This implies that the NumberDispatch define a generic constrained to a RecipientCatalog implementation. But since the RecipientCatalog also define a generic type constrained to the Recipient trait, I can't figure out a way to define this in the NumberDispatch struct.
Does anyone know if and how something like this could be done?
(Edit: Forgot the &self in the traits)

Does RecipientCatalog can have many associated recipients? If yes, can a NumberDispatch ever dispatch to more than one type of recipient?

A RecipientCatalog is only intended to only serve one type of associated recipient implementation.

In addition to what the answer provided, and which is almost certainly the right approach, you can also add a "phantom" field that represents R to the struct. That would allow it to work with your original formulation: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fbf3a6b25454daee255f5d25bf55c566
AFAIK in Rust, trait generics are strictly more powerful than associated types, so if you can do something with associated types, the same thing should be possible with generics (but possibly in a less ergonomic way).

Make it an associated type instead, if it can only be one type:
pub trait Recipient {
    fn receive(&self, number: i32);
}

pub trait RecipientCatalog {
    type Recipient: Recipient;
    fn lookup(&self, recipient_index: usize) -> &Self::Recipient;
}

pub struct NumberDispatch<C> {
    catalog: C,
}

impl<C> NumberDispatch<C>
where
    C: RecipientCatalog,
{
    pub fn dispatch(&self, number: i32) {
        let recipient_index = 0; // Would be lookup logic
        self.catalog.lookup(recipient_index).receive(number);
    }
}

I also removed the constraint on the struct because you are not supposed to put them there.

Well, thanks. I did fiddle with the idea of using an associated type, but somehow this (quite simple I may add) approach eluded me. I guess I was trying to make it more complicated than what made sense :-/ Anyway, thanks. This seems to actually do the trick :-D
